# Does Longley–Rice model model takes into consideration Fresnel zone?

Tags: wireless, propagation

To an extent I understand Fresnel zone.But do know how Longley–Rice model takes Fresnel zone? In other words, how Fresnel zone concepts takes into account by the Longley–Rice model? Any comment would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question is rather for physics forum.

Comment: Why don't you learn to learn more effectively... by choosing the right key words,,, http://radiomobile.pe1mew.nl/?Calculations:Propagation_calculation:Fresnel_zones

Comment: e.g. rf fresnel zone rice longley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(websearch)

> The great advantage of the ***Longley-Rice model*** is that by including digital elevation maps, the model is able to asses the received signal strength with good accuracy, including ***Fresnel zone clearance and diffraction effects.***

[image]